# PHP – Substitute multiple similar strings with other different strings

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a string that contains various instances of the plain text "[var-X]" where X can be any positive integer. I have no prior knowledge of how high X can go in any given script (however I can get it, if necessary).

Each of these [var-X] must be evaluated and substituted by a different string. The value of the different string depends on an external xml file which I have no problem parsing.

So, my question is, how do I go from

```
$str = "Hey I am some text,[var-1] a lot of these [var-3] parts will have to [var-9] go away and
be exchanged [var-2] by others";
```

plus (assume this stuff is inside a bigger xml)

```
(some xml...)
<Variation id="1">really</Variation>
<Variation id="2">quickly</Variation>
<Variation id="3">strange</Variation>
(some other xml...)
<Variation id="9">definitely</Variation>
(more xml...)
```

to

```
$str = "Hey, I am some text, really a lot of these strange parts will have to definitely go away
and be exchanged quickly by others";
```

Is the best way iterating through my xml first, finding out how high the integer goes and then iterating again with a strpos on the string?

How can I handle the fact that I might find [var-7] and [var-72] (don't know the length of the number in advance)?

Can this be done with a regular expression (assuming that once I have "[var-7]" and the "7" as an integer I still need to process some stuff to know what to place in its stead)?

I hope the question's clear. My uncertainty is mostly about the best method, because I would probably be able to hack together something, but it could be sluggish and ugly.

Comment: @AndyJones my current (as in testing right now) approach consists of: strpos "[var-", then strpos the next "]" and get the int value from the difference in positions with a substr. Evaluate it, substitute as necessary. Go to the next "[var-" until that strpos returns FALSE. It just feels a little clumsy.

Comment: gotcha - preg_match and preg_replace would be recommended - I'll add an answer then

Comment: How are you reading the XML?

Comment: @Campari iteration via SimpleXML, comparing "id" attribute and then some more stuff which was cut from this questions (irrelevant attributes etc). I have no trouble with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *preg_replace_callback* that allows you to use a function as replacement.

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback('~\[var-(\d+)]~', function ($match) { 
    return $var[$match[1]]; 
}, $txt);
```

If you want to extract the values from an XML document, using XPath is a good way. Example:

```
$str = "Hey I am some text,[var-1] a lot of these [var-3] parts will have"
     . " to [var-9] go away and be exchanged [var-2] by others";

$xml = <<<'LOD'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Variations>
    <Variation id="1">really</Variation>
    <Variation id="2">quickly</Variation>
    <Variation id="3">strange</Variation>
    <Variation id="9">definitely</Variation>
</Variations>
LOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$callback = function ($match) use ($xpath) {
    $var_node = $xpath->query("/Variations/Variation[@id='"
                             . $match[1] . "']/text()")->item(0);
    $var_content= $var_node->nodeValue;
    return $var_content;
};

$str = preg_replace_callback('~\[var-(\d+)]~', $callback, $str);
```

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, preg_replace_callback is called for every single match, correct? If that is the case, I think I have found my answer and thank you for it :) Edit: it all checks out, thanks again.

Comment: @user1989178: yes, it's the case. Why not use an XPath query to extract the values you need in your callback function?

Comment: I would gladly do that but am not familiar with XPath enough to dwelve into it now... also, some of the attrs in the XML need to be parsed and evaluated against session variables, which I'm not sure is extremely practical.

Comment: @user1989178: it's relatively easy to use in most cases. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use preg_replace_callback. In the code below I am using your array directly, but you say you want to read from xml, so your logic to read from it would replace the simple array access. You may also want to think about what you want to do in case the index doesn't correspond to anything in your xml. In the example below I am assuming you don't want to replace it at all, but this up to you.

```
$str = "Hey I am some text,[var-1] a lot of these [var-3] parts will have to [var-9] go away and be exchanged [var-2] by others";


$var[1] = "really";
$var[2] = "quickly";
$var[3] = "strange";
$var[9] = "definitely";

$done = preg_replace_callback('/(?P<original>\[var-(?P<index>\d+)\])/', function($match) use($var) {
    return isset($var[$match['index']]) ? $var[$match['index']] : $match['original'];
}, $str);

echo $done;
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarified the answer up there, I'd upvote you if I had such a possibility (which I now apparently do!)

Comment: Great! Make sure you don't forget the `use` part in your closure. Otherwise `$var` won't be available in the scope of that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid using preg_replace_callback you could do something like:

```
while(preg_match('/\[var-(\d+)\]/', $str, $m)){
  $str = preg_replace('/\[var-' . $m[1] . '\]/', $var[$m[1]], $str);
}
```